# Why is configuration Manager not showing?

Tags: c#

Why is ConfigurationManager class not showing?

```cs
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

I want to get the connection string from App.Config
I have .net 4.0v

Comment: Did you add the reference to System.Configuration?

Comment: Please don't use pictures for code.

Comment: @steve yes but the configuration Manager class is not showing  in the IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2):

It is insufficient to add just namespaces (using System.ConfigurationManager).
Hot to solve it follow the given steps.
First, go to Solution Explorer and you need to add a reference.
Right-click on reference > Add references > reference window will be opened and check on
System.Configuration.

Answer (score 1):

See the following working code sample where you need to change the actual connection strings in app.config for this to work. Also note this is a .NET Core Console project while the same works in .NET Framework 4.x
[source code](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/configuration-helpers/tree/master/ConsoleDemoAppConfig2)

**.NET Framework 4.x**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using static System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

namespace ConsoleDemoAppConfig2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using var cn = new SqlConnection(AppSettings["DevConnection"]);
            {
                try
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Open");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**.NET Core Code**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using static System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;

namespace ConsoleDemoAppConfig2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using var cn = new SqlConnection(AppSettings["DevConnection"]);

            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Open");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Code]

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="DevConnection" 
             value="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True" />
        <add key="StagingConnection" 
             value="Data Source=Staging;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True" />
        <add key="ProductionConnection"
             value="Data Source=Production;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: my question is ConfigurationManager class is not showing in the IntelliSense. I added System.configuration namespace as an assembly reference.

Comment: DId you add an using statement at the top of the class 


`using static System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager;`